# Getting a value of a table with maximum date and time

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

In my database (SQL Server 11), I have the next situation:

```
SELECT Npa, Vty, Dat, Hou FROM DleVldAud WHERE Npa = '4-130325x01'
```

Result:

```
_____Npa____|____Vty_____|___________Dat___________|___Hou___
4-130325x01 | Definitive | 2013-03-25 00:00:00.000 | 12:13:57
4-130325x01 | Sent BNP   | 2013-03-25 00:00:00.000 | 12:14:04
```

QUESTION is, I would like to get the value of `Vty` for a concrete `Npa` with higher (MAX) value of `Dat` and `Hou`... how?

In this case, I would like to get the 2nd row:

```
_____Npa____|____Vty_____|___________Dat___________|___Hou___
4-130325x01 | Sent BNP   | 2013-03-25 00:00:00.000 | 12:14:04
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

```
select top 1 vty
from t
where npa = @npa
order by dat desc, hou desc;
```

Comment: I was trying to figure out how to do a MAX of two columns, but this answer is really simple and correct... thanks!